# Automatically create a 'txt' file from a list in another txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have windows 7, and little/no programming experience, I was wondering if a simple .BAT file would suffice.

I have a list of 'names' that I have to create an individual text file on an on-going basis. The files are to have no content, just simply entered into a system as the file name. The volume of files could be 2-100 each time I want to use it.

I can place all the 'names' in a separate "extract.txt" file, each on a separate line. (The 'names' are generated using excel, and appending several descriptors, and finally stored as 'text')

I then want to create an individual text file for each line in "extract.txt".

e.g. Extract.txt file contains

```
GKL_ERT_55555_20170807143400_1
GKL_ERT_55556_20170807143400_1
GKL_ERT_55557_20170807143400_1
GKL_ERT_55558_20170807143400_1
```

I want 4 text files with no content in a folder named as

```
GKL_ERT_55555_20170807143400_1.CTR
GKL_ERT_55556_20170807143400_1.CTR
GKL_ERT_55557_20170807143400_1.CTR
GKL_ERT_55558_20170807143400_1.CTR
```

Comment: If the names are generated using Excel then, surely, you could find a VBA tutorial and get Excel to do this work, rather than going to an external process for something Excel can easily do???

Answer (score 1):

With a text editor, edit you list files to that each line reads:

```
echo "" >GKL_ERT_55555_20170807143400_1.CTR
```

Save as a .BAT, and execute in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

On cmd line use:

```
@for /f %A in ( Extract.txt ) Do @Type Nul > "%A.CTR"
```

In a batch double the `%` signs

```
@Echo off
for /f %%A in ( Extract.txt ) Do Type Nul > "%%A.CTR"
```